# Rewrite get params with htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching this for about 2 hours now and have tried every solution, but still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm working on writing an api. I'm trying to use "pretty" urls instead of having to pass params.

When I call `myurl.com/categories` it properly returns the entire list of categories.

When I call `myurl.com/categories/1`, which would then get the category with id=1, it returns a 404 error.

When I call `myurl.com/categories?id=1` it successfully returns the category with id=1.

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$ /categories.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Adding random stuff at the top did return a 500.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess to this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$ categories.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Tried that but I'm getting the same results as before.

Comment: Is `categories` a real directory by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try your rules this way and make the `/` optional as well.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)/?$ /categories.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```